# Cannot create play_evolutions table

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to run evolutions on a fresh database and it throws exceptions:

> Table 'calories.play_evolutions' doesn't exist.

I tried with MySQL and PostgreSQL and the same problem. Any ideas of why is happening?

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'calories.play_evolutions' doesn't exist]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:214)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:144)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:304)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1261)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:409)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'calories.play_evolutions' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.executeQuery(EvolutionsApi.scala:340)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:148)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:120)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:135)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was that I set the number of connections to 2; when I set the number of connections to 10 the evolutions ran successfully. I don't have an explanation of why it works.

> slick.dbs.default.db.numThreads=10
>
> slick.dbs.default.db.maxConnections=10